# call stored procedure dynamically from another procedure while passing values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

i need to call a stored procedure from another stored procedure.
The called stored procedure (sp_called) takes some input parameters let's say @x (int), @y (int).

now when I call sp_called from (sp_caller) how can I get the parameters values (x,y) dynamically from sp_called without having to set default values like i have done below (1,2)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCaller]
    @sp varchar(1000)   

AS
BEGIN   

declare @select varchar(max)    

create table #temp_tbl 
(
    Id int(5), Name char(50), Address char(50)
)

select [Id],[Name],[Address] into #temp_table   
from openrowset('SQLNCLI', 'Server=myserver;Trusted_Connection=yes;','exec [spGet_Called]' 1,2')


set @select = 'select * from #temp_table' 
    //do other stuffs here

exec(@select)   

END
```

thanks

Comment: Why are you calling the procedure as you are, via openrowset, rather than just calling it directly?

Comment: @david: I wanted to try that out so, just used it. So, could i achieve the result if i called it directly?

Comment: You can exec a stored proc into a temp table if that's what you mean...and use whatever parameters you need.

Comment: it is unclear what you are asking can you elaborate more ?

Comment: @arun: Instead of having to supply default values like i did which is 1,2 which is basically 2 types of parameter int type id in [spGet_called]. Now in order to execute [spGet_called], from [sp_caller], i would have to supply those 2 values. now i don't want to insert that manually in [sp_caller] procedure. I would like to retrieve those 2 parameters dynamically and execute that.

Comment: just create your second sp and fix those two parameters as input parameters and call your second sp from 1st and pass those two parameters from your first sp, it doesn't matter whether it is dynamic or hard coded. only thing is you have to give same name for those parameters

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you define the called stored procedure with some default parameter values and call this stored procedure without specifying the parameters??